# Electron webContents.send does not always work

Tags: javascript, electron

I use the following to send some data to another window;

```
try{ 
    win.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => win.webContents.send('send-data', data)); 
}
catch(err){
    console.log("Caught ",err);
}
```

And for receivig;

```
ipcRenderer.on('send-data', function (event,data) {     
    console.log("Loaded ", data);   
 });
```

The thing is, the "data" here is sometimes assembled very quickly and it works fine. However, sometimes it takes a while and the other window is already loaded at this point. No data is received in that case, and no error message either. But then I can simply use the following to send it without problems;

```
win.webContents.send('send-data', data)
```

I couldn't find a way to apply for both cases. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Electron doesn't have a function to wait for the window to load, then send a message, or send a message right away if the window's already loaded.

**However** this can be done with some simple code:

```js
var hasWindowLoaded = false;
var hasDataBeenSent = false;
var data            = {};

win.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    hasWindowLoaded = true;
    if (!hasDataBeenSent && data) {
        win.webContents.send('send-data', data);
        hasDataBeenSent = true;
    }
});

// Now add this where you build the `data` variable.
function loadData () {
    data = {'sampleData': 'xyz'};

    if (!hasDataBeenSent && hasWindowLoaded) {
        win.webContents.send('send-data', data);
        hasDataBeenSent = true;
    }
}
```

Once the data's loaded in `loadData` it'll check if the window's finished loading and if it has then it sends the data right away.

Otherwise it stores the data in a varible (`data`) and once the window loads it sends it to the window.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that you may want to consider is sending data to the `browserWindow` using query strings.

```js
const data = { hello: "world" }; // sample data

// send it using query strings
browserWindow.loadFile(YOUR_HTML_FILE_PATH, {
  query: { data: JSON.stringify(data) },
});


// parse this data in the browserWindow
const querystring = require("querystring");
const query = querystring.parse(global.location.search);
const data = JSON.parse(query["?data"]);
console.log(data); // { hello: "world" }
```

Comment: If the `data` variable is assembled after the browser window has loaded then wouldn't you have to reload the page with `data` in the query string in order for the browser window to receive the data?

Comment: The data will be in the url itself. It will be in the query strings. The fact the browser window is loaded or not does not matter.

Comment: @Joshua I think I have misunderstood the question. If you use the query strings method to send data, you need to wait for the data to be assembled then create the browser window.